# What is the correct type hint for class factory with multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, factory, multiple-inheritance, type-hinting

What is the correct return type of the following function?

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar['T']
U = typing.TypeVar['U']


def class_factory(class_T: typing.Type[T], class_U: typing.Type[U]) -> ???:
    return type(class_T.__name__ + '_x_' + class_U.__name__,
                (class_T, class_U), {})
```

Background: I am trying to convert a normal python class T to Subject class (Subject as in the observer pattern). My idea is to create class SubjectT inheriting from both T and Subject:

```py
import typing
T = typing.TypeVar('T')

def create_subject(class_T: typing.Type[T]) -> ???:
    class result_class(Subject, class_T):
        def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
            self.notify()   # notify observers of all changes
    return result_class
```

This works, but my IDE does not offer any code auto-completion for `result_class`.

Comment: For `class_factory`, since it returns the result of a `type()` call, probably would be `type`. And for `result_class`, ...also `type`, apparently. You can try creating a dummy class on a python command prompt and doing `type(dummy_class)` to see what type classes return as, and you can do the same for the result of the `type()` function

Comment: It's true that type(result_class)=type, but it would be interesting to express that result_class is a subtype of both Subject and class_T.

Comment: I think you are looking for [intersection types](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213), which unfortunately do not exist yet.